# If parameter is empty, change where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I have an Oracle function that has 3 parameters and uses parameters to set where clause values in multiple select statements that are union'd together. Here is the pseudo code:

```
create or replace function fn_newfunction
(IN_1_id in VARCHAR2, IN_2 in VARCHAR2, IN_3 in VARCHAR2)

RETURN T_varchar_table AS
v_tab T_varchar_table;

begin

  select
  cast(multiset (
         --add users
         select * from table1 opt where opt.col2 = IN_2 and opt.col3 = IN_3 and opt.col1 = IN_1_id
         union
         ...
         <insert 10+ select statements here with same values>

  ) as T_varchar_table)     
  END
    into v_tab
    from dual;
  return v_tab;
end;
```

A use case has come up to pass blank values into the function for any of the IN parameters and have it select ANY value in the where clause where the parameter is blank. An example is if IN_1_id is passed a blank value, the where clause in the first select statement would show where ANY value (even null) is in the opt.col1. How can I make this happen? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic I most frequently use, albeit not in Oracle, is the following. I've written it pseudo, simply because as I mentioned, I believe this more methodological question, as opposed to syntax.

### The Logic

```
Function (@Parameter1, @Parameter2)

SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE 
   --Parameter1
   (@Parameter1 IS NULL OR MyTable.Parameter1 = @Parameter1)
   AND
   --Parameter2
   (@Parameter2 IS NULL OR MyTable.Parameter2 = @Parameter2)
```

---

### Why It works

If you don't pass `@Parameter1`:

```
   --This evaluates to TRUE for every single row, because the first condition has been met
  (@Parameter1 IS NULL OR MyTable.Parameter1 = @Parameter1)
```

If you *do* pass `@Parameter1`:

```
   --The first condition will never be met, because @Parameter1 is NOT NULL.
   --The second condition will only be met for rows that match the parameter.
  (@Parameter1 IS NULL OR MyTable.Parameter1 = @Parameter1)
```

Using this method, you can conditionally add fields to  your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Prefixing  variables with `@` is invalid syntax in Oracle; apart from that the methodology is good.

Comment: As I'd mentioned, I wrote it in pseudo. I'm not very familiar with Oracle but I figured the logic was really the essential piece anyways.

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I needed - THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic sql to get your issue addressed

```
if IN_1_id is not null then
lv_where := ' and opt.col1 =IN_1_id1 ';
else
lv_where :=' ';
end if;
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select * from table1 opt where opt.col2 = IN_2 and     opt.col3 = IN_3 ' ||lv_where ;
```